# Bash Shell Script - ncrcat NetCDF operators

Tags: bash, shell, netcdf

I have several files, which I want to concatenate into a single file. Since I can call the files using a loop, I would like to use the command ncrcat to concatenate them. I know that with the way and the place that I write the ncrcat it cats only one file, the one in the loop at the moment, but I can not think of something else. My script is:

```
Vars1="Ad Ab Al"
Var2=Bs

for MyVar1 in $MyVars1 ; do

MyFile=${MyVar1}-${Var2}.nc
ncrcat $MyFile AllFiles.nc

done
```

Thank you for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With ncrcat you can use regular expressions to find the files, so there is no need to loop thru the variables.

```
ncrcat A[a-z]-Bs.nc AllFiles.nc
```

Read some on [regular expressions on nco commands](http://nco.sourceforge.net/nco.html#rx)

Answer (score 1):

To construct the list of files argument to ncrcat you could use command substituiton:

```
ncrcat $(find $NC_FILES_DIR -type f -name '*.nc') out.nc
```

where you define NC_FILES_DIR.